Orange Plant not flowering
I planted a seed from a orange in 2019 March
The plant has now grow into a tall 7 feet tree
But it has not flowered even once from the day it grew
What should I do?

More information please.  What soil is it in, how much sun and water does it get?

I don't live in an area where citrus can grow outside, but my general understanding is that most likely you should graft some known type of citrus to your seedling rootstock if you want better odds of edible and/or pleasant to eat fruit.
